# How to read data into Tensorflow?

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, tensorflow

I'm trying to read data from CSV files to tensorflow,

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#filenames-shuffling-and-epoch-limits

The sample code in official document is like this:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
```

To read the file, I need to know how many columns and lines in the file beforehand, and if there are 1000 columns, I need to define 1000 variables like `col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,..., col1000 ,` this doesn't look like an efficient way to read data.

My questions

1. What is the best way to read CSV files into Tensorflow ?
2. Is there any way to read Database (such as mongoDB) in Tensorflow ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You definitely don't need to define col1, col2, to col1000...

   generally, you might do things like this:

   ```
   columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
   features = tf.pack(columns)
   do_whatever_you_want_to_play_with_features(features)
   ```
2. I do not know any off-the-shelf way to directly read data from MongoDB. Maybe you can just write a short script to convert data from MongoDB in a format that Tensorflow supports, I would recommend binary form `TFRecord`, which is much faster to read than csv record. [This](https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-inputs-part1-placeholders-protobufs-queues/) is a good blog post about this topic. Or you can choose to implement a customized data reader by yourself, see [the official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/new_data_formats/index.html#custom-data-readers) here.

Answer (score 3):

```
def func()
    return 1,2,3,4

b = func() 

print b #(1, 2, 3, 4)

print [num for num in b] # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Hi its nothing to do with tensorflow its simple python need not define 1000 variable. tf.decode_csv returns a tuple.

No idea on database handling, I think u can use python and just input the data in the form of array to the tensorflow.

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

of course you can implement to directly read batch random sort trained data from mongo to feed to tensorflow. below is my way:

```
        for step in range(self.steps):


            pageNum=1;
            while(True):
                trainArray,trainLabelsArray = loadBatchTrainDataFromMongo(****)
                if len(trainArray)==0:
                    logging.info("train datas consume up!")
                    break;
                logging.info("started to train")
                sess.run([model.train_op],
                         feed_dict={self.input: trainArray,
                                    self.output: np.asarray(trainLabelsArray),
                                    self.keep_prob: params['dropout_rate']})

                pageNum=pageNum+1;
```

and also you need preprocess trained data in mongodb, such like: assign each trained data in mongodb a random sort value...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to read Database (such as mongoDB) in Tensorflow ?

Try [TFMongoDB](https://github.com/svenboesiger/tfmongodb), a C++ implemented dataset op for TensorFlow that allows you to connect to your MongoDB:

```
pip install tfmongodb
```

There's an example on the GitHub page on how to read data. See also [pypi: TFMongoDB](https://pypi.org/project/TFMongoDB/#description)